# UI not calling INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors()

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have a model implementing both `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. The Property changed event fires when ever I have a property modified, but for some reason when I raise the Error event handler, the UI does ever invoke the GetErrors method. This results in the validation error not being rendered to the UI.

Can someone take a look at how I have the INotifyDataErrorInfo set up and tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

**Base model implementation**

```
public class BaseChangeNotify : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private bool isDirty;

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public BaseChangeNotify()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isDirty;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isDirty = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.errors.Count(e => e.GetType() == typeof(ErrorMessage)) > 0;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) ||
            !this.errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return this.errors[propertyName];/*.Where(e => (e is ErrorMessage));*/
    }

    protected virtual void AddError(string propertyName, string error, bool isWarning = false)
    {
        if (!this.errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            this.errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();
        }

        if (!this.errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            if (isWarning)
            {
                this.errors[propertyName].Add(error);
            }
            else
            {
                this.errors[propertyName].Insert(0, error);
            }

            this.OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RemoveError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        if (this.errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) &&
            this.errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            this.errors[propertyName].Remove(error);

            if (this.errors[propertyName].Count == 0)
            {
                this.errors.Remove(propertyName);
            }

            this.OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        // Perform the IsDirty check so we don't get stuck in a infinite loop.
        if (propertyName != "IsDirty")
        {
            this.IsDirty = true; // Each time a property value is changed, we set the dirty bool.
        }

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // Invoke the event handlers attached by other objects.
            try
            {
                // When unit testing, this will always be null.
                if (Application.Current != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when an error has changed for this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    public virtual void OnErrorsChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.ErrorsChanged != null)
        {
            this.ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Model using the implementation**

```
public class PayItem : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private Section section;

    public Section Section
    {
        get
        {
            return this.section;
        }

        set
        {
            this.section = value;
            this.ValidateSection();
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ValidateSection([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        const string sectionError = "You must select a Section.";
        if (this.Section == null || this.Section.Name.Length > 1)
        {
            this.AddError(propertyName, sectionError);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RemoveError(propertyName, sectionError);
        }
    }
```

**The View trying to use it**

```
<ComboBox Name="SectionComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectSections}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPayItem.Section, 
                         NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The app is being wrote in WPF, and the WPF docs are pretty scarce. I've read through the [Silverlight documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on it [along with](http://blog.micic.ch/net/easy-mvvm-example-with-inotifypropertychanged-and-inotifydataerrorinfo) a few other [blog posts](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2013/7/13/utilizing-inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf-mvvm-app) I found [on the internet](http://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/) and have implemented in each of the different ways the blog authors suggest. Each time the result is the same, the `GetErrors()` method never gets hit by the Binding engine.

Can anyone see something that I'm doing wrong? When my model has its property set, I can step through the debugger and ultimately end up within the `OnErrorsChanged` event handler, and the event gets invoked. Nothing happens when it gets invoked though, so I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Johnathon

**EDIT**

Also I would like to note that I had been using IDataErrorInfo in the base class for the last couple of months without any issues. The binding worked, the errors were reported to the View and everything was happy. When I changed from IDataErrorInfo to INotifyDataErrorInfo, the validation appeared to stop communicating with the View.

Comment: Got `NotifyOnDataErrors=true` in your bindings?

Comment: I can't seem to find a NotifyOnDataErrors in any MSDN docs or in the Intellisense. I have however tried every combination of `NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` binding settings on the element attribute. None of which seem to result in GetErrors() being called.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyonvalidationerror(v=vs.110).aspx ya, ah well.  I'd use Snoop to validate your bindings next.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The INotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors property must return true when raising the ErrorsChanged event. Otherwise the binding engine ignores the errors. Your HasErrors property will return false all the time. This happens because you are checking for items of type ErrorMessage but your dictionary contains items of type KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>. Besides that it is highly inefficent to count all the items. You should use .Any() instead.

By the way, the MSDN documentation of INotifyDataErrorInfo says the following:

> Note that the binding engine never uses the HasErrors property,
>   although you can use it in custom error reporting.

This is plain wrong and it took me hours to find that out.

Comment: That makes sense. I'v moved off from INotifyDataErrorInfo and used a custom validation setup I wrote for Windows Phones in my WPF app. It worked with binding and different message types much in the same way. Thanks for following up though and catching my bug that prevented Errors from really returning